# An array of nonnegative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_{n,k}: 1 \leq k \leq n, n \geq 1\}$ be an array of nonnegative real numbers:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
x_{1,1} & & & & & \\
x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & & & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & & \\
x_{n,1} & x_{n,2} & \ldots & x_{n,n} & (\ast) \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
$$
If each element of the row $(\ast)$ converges to zero as $n$ tends to infinity (that is,

$x_{n,1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

$x_{n,2} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

$\qquad \vdots$

$x_{n,n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$)

then $\max(x_{n,1}, x_{n,2}, \ldots, x_{n,n})$ converges to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Thanks.

CJ

Comment: Did you try to make examples?

Comment: Do you have one?

Comment: The assumption $x_{n,1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ means that the sequence $(x_{n,1})$ goes to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. We may then understand that for every fixed $m$, $(x_{n,m})$ is a sequence. Furthermore the assumption $x_{n,n} \to 0$ means that there infinitely many of these sequences and their diagonal term goes to $0$. So the three dots between ($x_{n,2} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,) and ($x_{n,n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$) makes no sense...

Comment: In the row $(\ast)$ we have $n$ (different) sequences, all of them depending on $n$ and each of one converging to zero. It's just it.

Comment: I think your problem is not well formulated. As a proof, user133281 gave exactly the same answer than the one I deleted. You may consider a sequence of row, where the $n$-th row contains the $n$ term of $n$ different sequences $(x_{k,1})_{k \in \mathbb{N}},\ldots,(x_{k,n})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ and each of these sequences converge to $0$. But this is not what you written yet.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that for fixed $m$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n,m} = 0$, and that you want to know whether this implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \max(x_{n,1}, \ldots, \max_{n,n}) = 0$.

In that case, the answer is **no**. Consider the array with $1$s on the diagonal and $0$s below the diagonal. Then the sequence given by each column converges to $0$, whereas the sequence $\max(x_{n,1}, \ldots, \max_{n,n})$ is constant $1$.

**Edit:** If also the diagonals converge to $0$ ($\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n,n-k} = 0$ for all $k$), this still does not imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \max(x_{n,1}, \ldots, \max_{n,n}) = 0$. For instance, consider the example given by $x_{n,\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}=  1$ and $0$s everywhere else:

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & & & & & & \\
1 & 0 & & & & & \\
0 & 1 & 0 & & & & \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & & \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
&&& \vdots
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks to all that commented my post. The assumption $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n,m} = 0$ for fixed $m$ is only a part of the assumptions. Indeed, my assumptions are stronger than that in the sense that the sequence $x_{n,n}$ converges to zero (also the sequence $x_{n,n-1}$ converges to zero and so on). So, the array with $1$s on the diagonal and $0$s otherwise do not fits on the assumptions. As an example of what is the described triangular array consider $x_{n,k} = \frac{1}{kn}$, $1 \leq k \leq n$, $n \geq 1$.

Comment: So the assumptions are that all columns $x_{n,m}$ ($m$ fixed) and diagonals $x_{n,n-k}$ ($k$ fixed) converge to zero for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, precisely. That is also in my assumptions.

Comment: Well, what you wrote in your OP seems to me to be an unclear and ambiguous way of stating what I wrote in my previous comment.